# Почему в запросе с функцией count() срабатывает cross join?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, hibernate-criteria

Я делаю небольшое приложение на `spring mvc`, для работы с БД `Oracle` использую `hibernate`. Когда я делаю запрос в базу и выбираю все данные, получая список объектов, а потом беру размер этого списка, то всё работает как надо. Но тянуть все данные из базы плохо. Мне надо сделать запрос, который вернет число строк удовлетворяющих параметрам передаваемым в запрос. Для этого я пробую сделать запрос используя интерфейс `Criteria`. Создаю билдер, предикат и выполняю запрос, но результат получаю не тот, который ожидаю. Хибернэйт в запросе делает cross join и тогда перемножаются все строки в таблице на строки, которые содержат нужный параметр. В таблице всего 7 записей, из них удовлетворяющие по параметрам только 4. Результат запроса 28 вместо ожидаемых 4. Ниже привожу фрагменты кода.
Класс сущности:

```
@Entity(name = "Relationship")
@Table(name = "RELATIONSHIP")
public class Relationship extends IdEntity{
    private Long id;
    private User userFrom;
    private User userTo;
    private Date acceptedFriends;
    private RelationshipStatusType statusType;
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

    public Relationship() {
    }

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "R_SHIP_SQ", sequenceName = "RELATIONSHIP_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "R_SHIP_SQ")
    @Column(name = "RELATIONSHIP_ID")
    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_USER_FROM")
    public User getUserFrom() {
        return userFrom;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_USER_TO")
    public User getUserTo() {
        return userTo;
    }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "STATUS_TYPE")
    public RelationshipStatusType getStatusType() {
        return statusType;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "statuses")
    Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
```

Класс перечисления:

```
public enum RelationshipStatusType {
    REQUESTED("REQUESTED"),
    CANCELED("CANCELED"),
    DECLINED("DECLINED"),
    DELETED("DELETED"),
    ACCEPTED("ACCEPTED");

    private String value;

    RelationshipStatusType(final String value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.getValue();
    }
}
```

`DAO`:

```
@Repository("relationshipDAO")
@Transactional
public class RelationshipDAO extends GeneralDAO<Relationship> {

    private static final String GET_RELATIONSHIP = "SELECT * FROM RELATIONSHIP WHERE ID_USER_FROM = ? AND ID_USER_TO = ?";

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Relationship getRelationship(Long idUserFrom, Long idUserTo)throws InternalServerError {
        Relationship relationship;
        NativeQuery<Relationship> query = (NativeQuery<Relationship>) getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(GET_RELATIONSHIP, Relationship.class);
        try {
            relationship = query.setParameter(1, idUserFrom).setParameter(2, idUserTo).uniqueResult();
        }catch (NoResultException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
        return relationship;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public long getQuantityFriends(Long idUser, String status) throws InternalServerError{

        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Long> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
        Root<Relationship> relationshipRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Relationship.class);
        Predicate idUserPredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(relationshipRoot.get("userTo"), idUser);
        Predicate statusPredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(relationshipRoot.get("statusType"), RelationshipStatusType.valueOf(status));
        criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(criteriaQuery.from(Relationship.class)))
                .where(criteriaBuilder.and(idUserPredicate, statusPredicate));
        TypedQuery<Long> query = getEntityManager().createQuery(criteriaQuery);
        System.out.println("Quantity rows = " + query.getSingleResult());
        return query.getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

В результате запроса, в консоли вижу вот это:

```
23-May-2019 01:01:22.049 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator.initiateService HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: select count(relationsh1_.RELATIONSHIP_ID) as col_0_0_ from RELATIONSHIP relationsh0_ cross join RELATIONSHIP relationsh1_ where relationsh0_.ID_USER_TO=90 and relationsh0_.STATUS_TYPE=?
Quantity rows = 28
```

Почему вылазит `cross join` и как это исправить ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(relationshipRoot))
             .where(criteriaBuilder.and(idUserPredicate, statusPredicate));
```

Вызов `criteriaQuery.from(Relationship.class)` создает новый корень, который и добавляется в запрос c `cross join`. Об этом написано в документации к [`AbstractQuery.from`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/criteria/AbstractQuery.html#from-java.lang.Class-):

> Create and add a query root corresponding to the given entity, **forming a cartesian product** with any existing roots.

Comment: default locale, супер )) работает теперь ... большое спасибо за объяснение и за помощь

Comment: @YuriiS Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло